# set-progress only give 0 and 1 value in asi-http-request custom progress tracking

Tags: iphone, ios, asihttprequest

I want to display downloading progress bar ( HUD Progress bar) on ASIHttprequest library.
i tried this `[request setDownloadProgressDelegate:loadingHUD];
               [request setShowAccurateProgress:YES];
               [request setDelegate:self];`

But no luck it display blank at starting for downlaod and at end direct display full progress.
so i log the progress value and i got `set progress0.000000 set progress1.000000`.

How can i get accurate progress update to my HUD progress bar.

I send Json with data to my server and server verify that and and if its verify okay than send back me video data in response..i want to store that response into video file so i am using this

Here is my code

```
loadingHUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
loadingHUD.labelText = NSLocalizedString(@"Downloading", nil);
loadingHUD.mode=MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate;
[loadingHUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(verifyReceipt:) onTarget:self       withObject:transaction animated:YES];
// call the verify receipt method and download the file
 [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
     }
 - (void)verifyReceipt:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
 // string to NSdictionary and dictioanry to json string

NSArray *mainObjects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vendorId,deviceData,productID,nil]; // purchased Item ID of previous item
NSArray *mainKeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ID",@"device",@"video",nil];
NSDictionary *mainDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:mainObjects forKeys:mainKeys]; // final string of data
NSLog(@"Json Main dict created");
      NSString *sandBox=@"1";
   NSArray *testobj = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:mainDictionary,receiptDataEncoded,sandBox,nil]; // purchased Item ID of previous item
  NSArray *testkey = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"data",@"receiptData",@"sandbox",nil];
  NSDictionary *testdict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:testobj forKeys:testkey];         // final string of data
  NSLog(@"Json Main dict created");


  NSError *error;
  NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:testdict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
  NSString *resultAsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSLog(@"Purchase product Json string:\n%@", resultAsString);

 ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://testing.test.io/dev.php/video/verifyReceipt"]];


//[request setDidReceiveDataSelector:@selector(request:didReceiveBytes:)];
[request setPostValue:resultAsString forKey:@"verify"];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:120];
[request setNumberOfTimesToRetryOnTimeout:2];
// request.showAccurateProgress=YES;
 [request setDownloadProgressDelegate:loadingHUD];
 [request setShowAccurateProgress:YES];
 request setDelegate:self];
 //[request setDownloadProgressDelegate:self];

 // SAVED video PATH
 // Get the Document directory
 NSString *documentDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
 // Add your filename to the directory to create your saved pdf location
 NSString *movLocation = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[fileName st ringByAppendingString:@".mov"]];

  // TEMPORARY video PATH
  // Get the Caches directory
   NSString *cachesDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
  // Add your filename to the directory to create your temp pdf location
  NSString *tempMovLocation = [cachesDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[fileName stringByAppendingString:@".mov"]];

 // Tell ASIHTTPRequest where to save things:
 [request setTemporaryFileDownloadPath:tempMovLocation];
 [request setDownloadDestinationPath:movLocation];
 [request startSynchronous];

NSLog(@"Path is %@",movLocation);
   }

- (void)setProgress:(float)progress1
    {
[loadingHUD setProgress:progress1];
NSLog(@"set progress%f",progress1);
     }

   - (void)requestDone:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{
//[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

  if(request.responseStatusCode==200)
   {
    //BOOL success = [videoData writeToFile:movLocation atomically:NO];
   // NSLog(@"bool value is%d",success);
    NSLog(@"in request done sucsessfully downlaod and store in database %d",request.responseStatusCode);
    [DBHelper savePurchaseId:fileName];
    [self movieReceived];
       }
     else{

     NSLog(@"in request downlaod and store in database failed %@",request.responseHeaders);

 }
  }

     -(void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
   {

  NSLog(@"%@",request.error);

    }
```

IF i use didreceivebytes than my file wont get download ..

```
-(void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveBytes:(long long)bytes {
 NSLog(@"Received bytes:%lld",bytes); progress = 0.0f; if (progress < 1.0f)

 {
     progress = ((float)bytes) / 469690;
     NSLog(@"progress value is %f",progress);
     loadingHUD.progress = progress;
 }
```

}

any help is appreciated thank you

Comment: You had posted similar question before and I had answered it. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Adithya my problem is not solved thats why

Comment: Did you get the solution I had provided?

Comment: @Adithya i solve my problem..it was because of two ..first one is in asihttep i am using setpostvalue and afnetworking i am adding that post value in nddictioanry and second one is remove the [httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding]; in afnetworking

Answer (score 0):

i solve by using afnetworking 
and reloving setparameterencoding and adding post value in dictioanry

```
  NSString *documentDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
// Add your filename to the directory to create your saved pdf location
NSString* destPath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[fileName stringByAppendingString:@".mov"]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:/testing.io"]; // 
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
// [httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];// no need of this line remove 

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"dev.php/video/verifyReceipt" parameters:postRequest]; // /dev.php/video/verifyReceipt
NSLog(@"postRequest: %@", postRequest);

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:destPath append:NO];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     // Give alert that downloading successful.
     NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", destPath);


     // [self.target parserDidDownloadItem:destPath];

     HUD.detailsLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %i%%",@"Downloading",100];
     [HUD hide:TRUE];

     [DBHelper savePurchaseId:fileName];
     [self movieReceived];

 }
                                 failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
     // Give alert that downloading failed
     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

     // [self.target parserDidFailToDownloadItem:error];
     [HUD hide:TRUE];

 }];
[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
 {
     // Progress
     float totalProgress = (totalBytesWritten / (totalBytesExpectedToWrite * 1.0f) * 100);
     HUD.detailsLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Downloading %i%%", MIN((int)(totalProgress), 99)];
 }];
[operation start];
```

}